# Запустить kafka в docker, и получить к ней доступ из внешнего сервиса

Tags: spring, docker, apache-kafka

Только начал изучать докер. Идея следующая: Есть 2 spring boot сервиса, между которыми общение осуществляется через кафку. Хочу попробовать перенести все это в докер. Для начала решил перенести в докер кафку. Используя docker-compose поднимаю zooKeeper и кафку так:

```
networks:
kafka-net:
driver: bridge

services:
zookeeper-server:
image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
networks:
  - kafka-net
ports:
  - '2181:2181'
environment:
  - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
kafka-server1:
image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
networks:
  - kafka-net    
ports:
  - '9092:9092'
environment:
  - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-server:2181
  - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
  - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
depends_on:
  - zookeeper-server
```

используя команду `docker-compose -f ./compose.yaml up -d` у меня получается поднять и zookeeper и кафку, но почему то, мои сервисы не видят ее.
Вот конфиг класс consumer'a из сервиса:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
@Value("${kafka.server}")
private String kafkaServer;

@Value("${kafka.group.id}")
private String kafkaGroupId;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, BookingReceiptDto> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, BookingReceiptDto> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}
```

И проперти файл данного сервиса:

```
server.port=8081
kafka.consumer.id=consumerServer
kafka.producer.id=producerServer
kafka.server=localhost:9092
kafka.group.id=server.broadcast
```

Думаю, что возможно, причина в том что порты как то не так проброшены. Но вроде бы все делаю по мануалам, а эффекта нет. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: 1. находясь там, где yml-файл, введите `docker-compose ps` (у вас там используется `compose.yaml`, поэтому еще с ключиком `-f compose.yaml`). Это покажет и контейнеры, и их порты. например, `0.0.0.0:3320->3306` - это проброс порта 3320 с машины на 3306 в контейнере. 2. `kafka.server=localhost:9092` - а вот это уже интересно. Сервер приложений тоже в контейнере? Или прямо на машине, без контейнеров? Если внутри дрогого контейнера, то `localhost:9092` конечно же не подойдет, так как внутри контейнера локалхост - это этот же контейнер!

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо! Сервер не в контейнере. Сервер на компе запускается в контейнере только пока что кафка

Comment: Какую OS используете? Как дела обстоят с файрволами? Я проверил вашу конфигурацию на Win10 - compose рабочий. Доступ к кафке по localhost есть.

Comment: Использую win 8. А вот про файрволы не подумал. Попробую нарыть инфу как его вырубить. Если Вы знаете, можете смело писать) Спасибо огромное за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что необходимо прокидывать другие порты.
Вот как должен выглядеть zookeeper:

```
zookeeper:
   image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
   environment:
     ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
     ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
   ports:
     - 22181:2181
```

А вот так кафка:

```
kafka:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - 29092:29092
  environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Тогда все поднимается отлично. Если же вам надо из своего сервиса, развернутого в контейнере получить доступ к кафке, это делается так:

```
receipt:
  container_name: receipt
  build: ./receipt
  ports: 
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
    KAFKA_SERVER: kafka:9092
  depends_on: 
    - kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

[QUESTION] Flush returned with error code -185: 'Local: Timed out' - название ошибки, которое я пытался исправить. Данная ошибка возникла при добавлении в Laravel - Kafka и соответственно добавлении в инфраструктуру новых сервисов, это Kafka контейнер и Zookeeper контейнер.
Мне помогли следующие 2 ответа:

1. Пояснение [git](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-kafka/issues/149#issuecomment-1491906097)
2. Откуда брал информацию [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768433/cannot-connect-to-kafka-which-is-outside-of-network)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin перепроверь пожалуйста, я исправил, спасибо:)